# Changing screen gives undefined props.navigation error react native

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am trying to change screen after few seconds which is for splash screen effect in react native. I have a main screen in which app originates. The code for first screen is:

```
import HomeUp from './HomeUp' 
import Splash from './Splash'
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class OriginPage extends Component {

constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.state = {
   component : <Splash />
 }
}

componentDidMount(){

   // Start counting when the page is loaded
   this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(()=>{
   // Add your logic for the transition
   this.setState({ component: <HomeUp /> })
   }, 5000);
}

componentWillUnmount(){
   clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle); 
}

render() {

return (
  this.state.component
     );
   }
}
```

My splash screen is :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar , View , Text , ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
export default class Splash extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 , justifyContent: 'center' , alignItems: 'center' , backgroundColor : '#34495e'}}>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor="#2c3e50" barStyle="light-content"/> 
                <Text style={{ color : 'white',fontSize : 18 }}>Hello Splash</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator color={'white'}/> 
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Till now everything works fine and the screen change over after 5s also working but this below code has bug.

```
       import React, { Component } from "react";
        class HomeUp extends Component {

        render () {
            const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
            return(
               <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => navigate("Products", { product: item })} underlayColor="transparent">
                  <View style={styles.view} >
                  <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.images[0].src}} />
                  <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight> 
);
}

}
```

Loading this screen alone have no bug but while changing screen I get `undefined navigation.props` error. hanks in adavanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deconstructing your navigation props in your HomeUp component you should do it as follows:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
```

Or also:

```
const navigate = this.props.navigation;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While clicking on the item to navigate undefined is not an object navigation.navigate error